# How can I utilize a secondary class to handle my events?

Tags: java, class, menu, actionlistener, menubar

I've created two separate classes whereas I have instantiated my menu bar, and a second class to handle the events; since I do have a lot of options on the menu bar I'd like to handle.

I have the menu bar and it's structure all set up, now the next step is to handle the events when the user clicks an option on the menu bar.

Here's a snippet of two items from my main menu-bar class:

```
    JMenuItem addOrangeItem = new JMenuItem("Orange");
    addOrangeItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener().orangeActionPerformed(e));

    JMenuItem addAppleItem = new JMenuItem("Apple");
    addAppleItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener().appleActionPerformed(e));
```

Here's my event handling class:

```
public class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

    public void orangeActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("I have chosen an orange!");
    }


    public void appleActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("I have chosen an apple!");
    }
}
```

The problem lies on this line of code in my main menu-bar class:

`addAppleItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener().appleActionPerformed(e));` whereas the `e` for my ActionEvent is underlined as red and I'm not sure what to do to get it working.

The goal of my code is to select the Apple/orange item/s and my event handling class will then return some code.

My question is how can I edit the above line of code so that I can then handle my menu bar items correctly?

If you require any more information, please let me know and I will get right onto that.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: the line should be `addAppleItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());` - basically you add an instance of a MenuActionListener as an ActionListener to the object addAppleItem - before you executed a function and tried to add the return value of that function as an ActionListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an invalid syntax :`addActionListener(new MenuActionListener().orangeActionPerformed(e))` .

`addActionListener` wants an `ActionListener` object, not `void` (which is the result of `new MenuActionListener().orangeActionPerformed(e)`), and also `e` is an unknown variable here.

This will work : `addActionListener(new MenuActionListener())` , but since you need different actions depending on the pressed item, you may use the action command system :

Set an action command on your `JMenuItem` (also note that one instance of `ActionListener` is enough for both buttons) :

```
ActionListener listener = new MenuActionListener();

JMenuItem addOrangeItem = new JMenuItem("Orange");
addOrangeItem.setActionCommand("orange");// set action command
addOrangeItem.addActionListener(listener);

JMenuItem addAppleItem = new JMenuItem("Apple");
addAppleItem.setActionCommand("apple");// set action command
addAppleItem.addActionListener(listener);
```

Then retrieve the action command in the listener (in `actionPerformed`), and decide what to do  :

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

        public void orangeActionPerformed() {
            System.out.println("I have chosen an orange!");
        }

        public void appleActionPerformed() {

            System.out.println("I have chosen an apple!");

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {

            String command = e.getActionCommand();

            switch (command) {

            case "orange":
                orangeActionPerformed();
                break;
            case "apple":
                appleActionPerformed();
                break;
            default:

            }

        }
    }
```

Note that `setActionCommand` is a method  from [AbstractButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html), and also works for `JButton` for instance.